# Annotating the intersecting point coordinates in the graph (python)

Tags: python, graph, data-visualization, project, data-analysis

In the code, I have figured out the intersection point of two lines (22,50) and I want to show this in the graph (have an arrow pointing at the intersection point with (22,50)) and wondering if the community can help me with this.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from shapely.geometry import LineString

df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/rajaa/Desktop/tril.csv")

t = df['time']
mu = df['material uts']
ps = df['pipe stress']

 plt.figure(figsize = (8,5), dpi = 100)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

plt.plot(t,mu,'r', label='Material UTS')
plt.plot(t,ps, 'b--',label=[enter image description here][1]'Pipe Stress as the pipe is depressurized')

plt.title('Graph 1', fontdict={'fontname': 'Arial', 'fontsize': 20})

plt.xticks(np.arange(0,32,2))
plt.yticks(np.arange(0,120,10))

plt.xlabel('Time (minutes)')
plt.ylabel('Pipe stress and UTS (MPa)')

plt.legend()

first_line = LineString(np.column_stack((t, mu)))
second_line = LineString(np.column_stack((t,ps)))
intersection = first_line.intersection(second_line) 

plt.plot(*intersection.xy,'ro')

x,y = intersection.xy


plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ax.arrow(0, 0, 22, 50, head_width=0.05, head_length=0.1, fc='k', ec='k')
```